# What is the integer range in element range index

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-10

I create `range-element-index` on `property_x`, I set `scalar-type` to `int` and I want to perform `jsonPropertyRangeQuery` on it. But for value that are technically valid it throw error: `No decimal element range index for property_x`.

Before I perform `jsonPropertyRangeQuery` I check if type of number is in integer range like in this way: `xdmp.type(100000025131)` and it return `'integer'` so I think it is correct value because `xdmp.type(10000002513100000))` will return `'double'`.

How I can check if the value are able to be use in `jsonPropertyRangeQuery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index the value as `xs:long` and then you can search without error:

```
cts.search(cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery("property_x", "=", 2147483647))
```

I think there may be some confusion and issues between JavaScript `Number`  (and in newer version of V8 that MarkLogic isn't yet using, `BigInt`) and XML Schema numeric types and ranges for `xs:int` and `xs:integer`, `xs:long`, `xs:unsignedLong`, etc.

Although, `xdmp.type(100000025131)` returns `integer`, and `parseInt('100000025131') === 100000025131` returns `true`.

- `xs.int('100000025131')` (max is `2147483647`) throws:

  > [javascript] XDMP-CAST: function bound ()() -- Invalid cast: "100000025131" cast as xs.int
- `xs.unsignedInt('100000025131')` (max is `4294967295`) throws:

  > [javascript] XDMP-CAST: function bound ()() -- Invalid cast: "100000025131" cast as xs.unsignedInt
- `xs.integer('100000025131')` returns `xs.integer` with the value `100000025131`
- `xs.long('100000025131')` returns `xs.long` with the value `100000025131`

There is an option for indexing as `xs:int`, `xs:unsignedInt`, `xs:long`, and `xs:unsignedLong`, but not `xs:integer`.

It would be good if you could open a [MarkLogic Support ticket](https://help.marklogic.com/) and ask for clarification about why `xdmp.type(100000025131)` reports `integer`, or maybe what documentation there is (or needs to be) to describe how the simple type `integer` maps to the schema types `xs.integer`, `xs.int`, `xs.long`, etc.?

Comment: Yes, but 100000025131 > 2147483647

Comment: whoops, totally didn't notice! Too many digits and no grouping made that harder to spot. Then this may just be that the number really isn't an `int` and shouldn't be indexed as one. Still may have some issues that it says it is. I'll do a little more investigation and update this answer.

Comment: One curiosity: if the range index is set to "invalid values' : reject, then I woul expect that this would have been made clear by the server rejecting documents with values not matching the datatype. Too many digits for xs:int should have been caught at ingest in that case.

Comment: Ok, so I changed scalar-type to "long" and still get same error.

Comment: And it's done reindexing? I inserted a doc with that value, set my index to long, and it returns the doc.

Comment: Also, which version of MarkLogic are you using?

Comment: You are right, the db are under reindexing. Now is working.